# WCF callback to AJAX alternative

Tags: c#, ajax, wcf

Hi from what I read you cannot use a duplex channel an have call backs to ajax from wcf.

However.....

I have managed to achieve this to some effect by using an asynchronous server operation as shown below.

```
public async Task<int> Test()
{
    return await Task.Run(() =>
    {
        Thread.Sleep(5000);
        return 1;
    });
}
```

At the moment I call this method when the web app starts and hey bristo 5 seconds later I get a callback.  Now I have tested this all in same development environment and it works like a charm even for long periods over 20 minutes, however I am left feeling like I have abused wcf somewhat and it does not feel right. Not 100% sure this would work in live either.

Does anybody see any issues with using this as some form of call back or should I revert to pollng the server?

Comment: I don't see any WCF code, and a callback fucntion.

Comment: I only included the one function from the service,  The rest of the contract is unrelated to the question. I refreshed my browser and I can see the function clearly.

Comment: public async Task<int> Test()
{
    return await Task.Run(() =>
    {
        Thread.Sleep(5000);
        return 1;
    });
}